# How to calculate length of an environment variable

Tags: batch-file

This may have been solved, but I looked and couldn't find a satisfactory answer.  How does one *quickly* calculate the length of an environment variable in a .bat script?

My problem involves environment variables of a couple thousand characters (I understand the practical limit is around 8k... the max size of a command line).

The straightforward approach simply counts characters.  I'll use %path% below as an example.  Assume the environment variable is known to exist -- which it does in my case -- so its length is at least 1.  No special characters (eg double-quote) are involved:

```
@echo off& setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a length=1
:loop
if not "!path:~%length%,1!"=="" set /a length+=1& goto loop
```

This calculates and leaves the value in environment variable 'length'. 
I have seen such solutions, but they are extremely slow for longer length variables.  A better approach (a couple order of magnitudes faster, and deterministic) is a binary search, such as:

```
@echo off& setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a p2=16384, length=p2-1
:loop
if "!path:~%length%,1!"=="" set /a length-=p2
if !p2! geq 2 (set /a length+=p2/=2& goto loop) else set /a length+=1
```

I suppose I can live with that, but still I wonder if I'm being stupid and missing something obvious.  I am looking for a pure .bat solution.

below added 6/12/2017

Learning from [this method](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#strLen) suggested by Compo led me to solution simpler/faster then dostips' (18% faster over all strings length 1 .. 8k).  That seemed significant enough to post:

```
@echo off& setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
set "str=A%path%"
set length=0
for %%p in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
  if not "!str:~%%p,1!"=="" set "str=!str:~%%p!"& set /a length+=%%p
)
```

Comment: You could try [this method](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#strLen) if you wish.

Comment: Thank you that is a cleaner solution.  It gets rid of a label -- always a good thing -- by performing the binary search using **for** .  The dostips.com code is also 20% faster (benchmarked on an 8K string) than what I came up with.

Comment: For fast, pure batch solutions you can look at [Dostips: strLen boosted](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1429)

Comment: I stripped out all overhead (creation of string, returning length from calling a bat, etc) -- ie. benchmarked just the 3 or 4 lines of .BAT code that calculate the length.  I did this within a single .BAT script that calculated the length of every string from 1..8000 characters.  The dostips.com solution took 16,271 ms, the 6/12 approach above took 10,899 ms.  That's a 33% reduction -- significant.  The "writing a file" approach (to a RAM disk) and using %%~zF was the fastest of all at 9,142 ms, though that's not an approach I would consider.

Comment: To be honest, if I were you, I would use the 6/12 method too. My writing to a file requires dealing with file permissions/ disk size and a lot of other things. But I'm glad to know that my solution is the fastest among all.

Comment: Yes I avoid creating temp files if at all possible because one must create a unique temp file name (multiple tasks can be running and filenames may collide), and what drive do you use, and is it full, etc...  Solving those problems can be more difficult/time-consuming than the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### PURE BATCH

```bat
@echo off

del temp.txt

for /F "delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /N "<resource>" "%~F0"') do set "start=%%G"
(for /F "usebackq skip=%start% delims=" %%G in ("%~F0") do echo %%G) > temp.txt
  rem echo everything after "<resource>" - code by @Aacini

for %%G in (temp.txt) do set /a size=%%~zG - 2
  rem get the file length and remove the CR\LF count

echo %size%
pause
exit/b
<resource>
things to test length
and can be mutli-line
```

This script echoes the string to file, and use a for loop to retrieve the file size, which is the string length. **To maximize speed, [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) it.**

Some facts:

- It took around `.54` seconds to process a `1.04 mb` long string.
- Getting the length of a `1.04 MB` string is more efficient than getting a string with 1-byte length.

---

#### OLD POWERSHELL

You can bypass the 8191 bytes limit by calling Powershell.

```bat
echo $characters = "yourString" > temp.ps1
echo $x= $characters.length >> temp.ps1
echo write-host $x >> temp.ps1

powershell -command "C:\PathToPS1file\temp.ps1

del /f /s /q temp.ps1
```

This is a slow powershell method, and requires lots of escaping.

Comment: You can't echo a string longer than 8191 bytes, as cmd.exe doesn't provide longer lines. Btw. Your solution works, but it's slow and it can't handle all strings, like `"&"""`&&`, as you need to escape the string for the batch and also for powershell parser

Comment: You're correct, I will edit my post according to your comment

Comment: I can't see here _fast processing_, your version takes 10110 milli seconds vs 80ms with the version Compo mentioned! I tested with a loop of 10 times calculating the string len. Your version is only 126 times slower than the pure batch solution

Comment: OK. I see. Probably computer issue. I will check the details later as I am going to sleep.

Comment: The PS solution imply to load and execute the 460 Kb `powershell.exe` file. In your timing you forgot to include the PS file loading time. There is no way that a powershell solution be faster than a pure Batch one when the process is simple and short...

Comment: @Aacini You're definitely correct(I tested the script in PS ISE instead from CMD). I've updated to a quick method.

Comment: @Jeb, after testing, my old PowerShell solution was not so perfect and *fast*, I've updated to a pure batch solution that *should* be even faster then Compo's solution.

Comment: why do you remove the previous version here? It may still be relevant. And your method doesn't work if the string contains newlines

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I've solved the issues you suggested, see the newest edit.

Comment: Even your new versions is slower than the dostips version, as writing a file is always slower than some internal commands. Btw. As a batch variable can hold maximal 8191 characters, I don't understand what you have tested with 106kB? Btw2: outputting strings via `set /p` will strip of leading white spaces and it is always limited to 1021 bytes

Comment: @jeb, I understand that it is slower than the dostips version, but I didn't use variable`(I don't understand where did I use variable?)` And in the test of 106kB, I used a randomly generated string.

Comment: @jeb Benchmarked (omitting any "special characters" handling code) calculating the length of a 64-char environment string: (1) the 6/12 solution at top == 6ms; (2) the dostips solution == 11ms; (3) the "write file" solution to a RAM disk == 7ms.  I looped 10,000 times across each solution within a single .bat file.  I'd love to see other benchmarks on this topic.